# EF one to one relationship when neither are primary keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have 2 entities that need to map together.  Since they are both database views, neither is technically a primary key.

```
 [Table("Name")]
    public class MemberInfo
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public string MemberId { get; set; }

        [Column("first_name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Column("last_name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Designation { get; set; }

        [Column("full_name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }



public class ChangeLog
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("asset_id")]
        public virtual Asset AssetID { get; set; }

        [Column("member_id")]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }

        public virtual MemberInfo MemberInfo { get; set; }

        [Column("comment")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        [Column("createdDT")]
        public DateTime CreatedDT { get; set; }
    }
```

If I try to access MemberInfo from ChangeLog I get an error saying:

```
A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the query returned more than one related object. This is a non-recoverable error.
```

The MemberID field for MemberInfo is unique.  I need to be able to access the MemberInfo properties from ChangeLog through the MemberInfo Property.

Comment: Not sure if that will solve the issue for you, but you should add the ForeignKey attribute on your MemberID field in the ChangeLog class. I'd also add the Key attribute on identifier fields that you have (ID and MemberId)

Comment: I just noticed in your title that you want a one-to-one relationship. In that case, you should add a reference field in your Member class to ChangeLog. Right now, based on your model specification, more than one ChangeLog(s) can be linked to a member. By adding that reference, you would enforce a 1-1 relationship.

Comment: When I add a reference to ChangeLog in Member, I get an error saying "Invalid column name 'ChangeLog_ID'."

Comment: What is the name of the foreign key column in the Name table (MemberInfo object) that points to the ChangeLog table?  Ameen is right you're going to need a reference to ChangeLog in yoru MemberInfo class, and you're also going to have to do some configuration to make this work.

Comment: Jeff, there is not a foreign key object that points to the ChangeLog table.  I'm hoping that I can access the MemberInfo members by using the MemberID field in Changelog (which corresponds to ID in MemberInfo)

Comment: Well the answer was painfully obvious once I thought about it.  I needed to setup a many-to-one relationship between Members and changelog (many members can edit a single asset).  Duh.

Answer (score 1):

this error is for Asset property in ChangeLog class
you dont write that class
i think with changing that property you can fix this error